# send multipart upload with json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a video file along with some JSON using a REST API with requests in Python.

Here is the example cURL for the request.

```
curl -XPOST -i "https://io.cimediacloud.com/upload" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F filename=@Movie.mov
-F metadata="{ 'metadata' : { 'Resolution' : '1080p', 'Language' : 'English' },        
'workspaceId' : 'a585b641a60843498543597d16ba0108', 'folderId' : 
'a585b641a60843498543597d16ba0108' }"
```

And here is my code.

```
url = 'https://io.cimediacloud.com/upload'
files = {'file': ('video.mp4', open('files/video.mp4', 'rb')),
                  }
data = {'metadata': {'Resolution' : '1080p', 'Language' : 'English'},
        'workspaceId': your_workspace_id,
        'folderId': folder_id,}

r = session.post(url, files=files, data=data)
```

When I run this, the API server returns a MissingOrInvalidFileName error. If I leave out my data parameter, the file uploads correctly. What is the correct way to make this request?

Comment: Technically, the CURL command is not posting JSON; the format is not valid. If the server still accepts that, it is using a very lenient parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file parameter is called `filename` in the curl request, and the `metadata` part should be a string (encoded to JSON); it is *one* field and has a *nested* `metadata` object. `wordspaceId` and `folderId` are keys *in* the outermost `metadata` object, not separate parameters:

```
import json

files = {'filename': ('video.mp4', open('files/video.mp4', 'rb')),
metadata = {
    'metadata': {'Resolution': '1080p', 'Language': 'English'},
    'workspaceId': your_workspace_id,
    'folderId': folder_id
}
data = {'metadata': json.dumps(metadata)}
r = session.post(url, files=files, data=data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am getting the same problem even after your suggestion :/ Any other points?

Comment: @jahmezz you could try `str()` instead of `json.dumps()` although that looks totally off-base if the documentation tells you it is JSON they want. Other than that my answer replicates what the `curl` command sample produces. Without more documentation on the API, I can't say anything else.

Comment: Hey, something I noticed when printing my request body was my json data was being printed in the body before the file to upload. The request body was listing `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="workspaceId"` and on before the file itself. Is this acceptable? @Martijn Pieters

Comment: Yes, elements in `data` are listed first; you can make `files` a *sequence* instead of a dictionary and add the metadata field to that to control order precisely: `files = (('filename', ('video.mp4', open('files/video.mp4', 'rb'))), ('metadata', (None, json.dumps(metadata))))`, then `r = session.post(url, files=files)`.

Comment: Could it be that the API server requires filenames for the data objects as well? Or requires the file to be first in the request body?

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect it is the API server expecting a filename on the first body entity. @Martijn Pieters

Comment: I doubt a filename is needed for the metadata field; the curl sample doesn't use it. There is not enough context to say anything about the order; it is possible but usually unlikely. I'd contact the people responsible for the API you are trying to use about that sort if thing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved! Turns out requests encodes its multipart with data then files while the API required files then data.

@Martijn Pieters's solution of inputting all of the data as tuples almost works. The only problem is setting the data this way breaks requests' ability to set the content-type header automatically (it thinks my data is content-type application/json).

In the end, I used [request-toolbelt](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt)'s MultipartEncoder which allows me to order my multipart body using tuples and saves the content-type in its instance. Here is the final working code.

```
m = MultipartEncoder([('filename', ('video.mp4', open('files/video.mp4', 'rb'))), 
                      ('metadata', json.dumps(metadata))])

r = session.post(url, data=m, headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
```

Finally works.